# MSAL provider: how to add redirect / popup to MS login in config

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to impose MSAL to my React application with @azure/react package, following the below guide:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/initialization.md#redirect-apis

The guide does not mentioned clearly that, where should I add the redirect API in order to make my application redirect to MS login page, or popup the login page?

Below is my index.js, which would show directly returned my App.js without logging in:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'index.css';
import App from 'App';
import * as serviceWorker from 'serviceWorker';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import reducer from 'store/reducer'

import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { Configuration,  PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";

//, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
const store = createStore(reducer);

const configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '*************',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*************'
  }
};

const pca = new PublicClientApplication(authProvider);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
        <App />
    </MsalProvider>,
   </Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: The link you shared has provided a sample here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/VanillaJSTestApp2.0/app/onPageLoad.

Comment: Hi did you check the link above? Any updates?